# iPhone SDK: submit username and password to facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I wanted to make a sort of app that can access facebook, but to log in I don't want to use a webview, I want to use two textfields with a username and password for facebook. When they press the log in button, it will send the text in the username and password to the facebook server or queries and be abel to log in and display a webview with the logged in webview. Is there any possible way to do this or do you need access to Facebook queries? Just wondering if it was possible or not, thanks.

Comment: I'd discourage you from trying to do this (and I hope there is not a way to do that). I'd discourage users from ever entering their password in any interface other than the Facebook UI or in the system settings. I assume you don't have nefarious intent, but in the hands of a less scrupulous developer, they could build (and sell) a database of captured Facebook passwords.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with doing this. I assume the developer isn't planning to do anything illegal. I'd like to be able to do this to support multiple users on one device - passwords could be stored securely in the keychain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this tutorial...... This site has lots of insights on how you might achieve that.......

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app